# Login system with php and my sql? stuck and wont work

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've created a login system using session start and put it on to my website however it just looks anyone in even when nothing has been typed and adds them to the database, Whats wrong with this code? I cant even get the validation of it to work it comes up blank and still logs in. the connection.php includes session_start() and the database connection

**loginform.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homecss.css"/>
<div id="form">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post" action="loginSubmit.php">
User Name: <br/>
<input type="name" name="username" type="text" /><br />
Password: <br/>
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="logsubmit" value="Login" />
</form></div>
```

**login.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homecss.css"/>
<?php
include './connection.php';
?>
<div id="form">
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['authenticatedusername'])){
include './loginform.php'; 
if (!empty($_POST["username"])) {
echo "Username is required";
}
if (!empty($_POST["password"])) {
echo "Password is required";
}
}
else{  
echo 'welcome   '. $_SESSION['authenticatedusername'];
echo '<br/><a href ="logout.php"> logout </a>';
echo '<br/><a href ="account.php"> My account </a>';

}

if (isset($_SESSION['message'])){
echo $_SESSION['message']="login failed";
}

?>
</div>
```

loginsubmit.php

```
<?php
include "./connection.php";
if(isset($_POST['logsubmit'])){
$user=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$user' AND user_password='$pass'";
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$_SESSION['authenticatedusername']=$user;
header ("Location: homepage.php");

} else{
echo 'Login Failed';
header("Location: homepage.php");
}
}
```

Comment: did you ever started the session ? `session_start()`

Comment: yes it is what is included in my connection.php

Comment: **Note**: Your data is prone to SQL injection attacks. Make sure to escape strings and use prepared statements. Also plain-text passwords are a bad idea. Apart from that how are you setting and un-setting your logged-in session `authenticatedusername`?

Comment: @b1234 Why do you have 2 login scripts

Comment: should i get rid of one?

Comment: no I see what you are trying to do

Comment: do you know how to improve it or just get it to work? I'm a beginner with php and not really sure where to go from here

Comment: `if ($row = mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){` instead of `if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){`

Comment: thankyou! I did that and now it no longer adds it to the database which is good, it just doesnt come up with an error message such as login failed? do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You're welcome. Did you try Meda's answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a little simpler:

First page no need to include connection, present the form, or log out button:

```
<?php
session_start();//move this to the top of the page
if(!isset($_SESSION['authenticatedusername'])){
    include './loginform.php'; 
}
else{  
    echo '<br/><a href ="logout.php"> logout </a>';
    echo '<br/><a href ="account.php"> My account </a>';
}
```

**loginSubmit.php**

Use [prepared](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) statements, to avoid SQL injection

```
<?php
session_start();
include './connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['logsubmit'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    /* query*/
    $sql = "SELECT user_name, user_password 
            FROM users 
            WHERE user_name=? AND user_password=?";
    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)) {
        /* bind parameters for markers */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        /* execute query */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        /*check for count*/
        if ($row = mysqli_num_rows($stmt) >0){
            /* bind result variables */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);
            /* fetch value */
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);   
            //printf("username = %s | password = %s\n", $username, $password);
            $_SESSION['authenticatedusername'] = $username;
        }else{
            echo "user not found";
        }
        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    /* close connection */
    mysqli_close($connection);

    if (isset($_SESSION['authenticatedusername'])){
        header ("Location: homepage.php");
    } else{
        header ("Location: login.php");//go back to login
        //you can send errors back or do something.
    }
}
```

If you are looking for improvement, don't store the password in plain text.

Read [Safe Password Hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Instead you create a field to store Hashes, you populate it like this for example:

```
$hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

You can use your own salt, but this is fine:

then when you query you check this way:

```
#get hash value from db and store it in $hash
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $hash)) {
    // Success!
}
else {
    // Fail !
}
```

---

And last advice if you want improvement, you can use the object oriented style of mysqli, and use functions and classes. Read up on OOP for that.

And you can take a look at [PDO (PHP Data Objects)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). It is a little easier to use and more flexible.

Comment: thankyou so much it does seem a lot simpler. The first bit of the code would i put that into login.php? i copied your code however it didnt login the user, on the query where you put user=? do i change those question marks?

Comment: @b1234 thats the prepare placeholder, it is populated by `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);`

Answer (score 0):

your `loginform.php` same as default

> loginsubmit.php

```
<?php
 include "./connection.php";
 if(isset($_POST['logsubmit'])){
    $user=$_POST['username'];
    $pass=$_POST['password'];
    $query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='".$user."' AND user_password='".$pass."'";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if($result != ''){
    $_SESSION['authenticatedusername']=$user;
       header ("Location: homepage.php");
    } else{
       echo 'Login Failed';
       header("Location: homepage.php");
    }
}
?>
```

> homepage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['authenticatedusername'] == ''){
    header('Location:loginform.php'); 
}
else{  
    echo '<br/><a href ="logout.php"> logout </a>';
    echo '<br/><a href ="account.php"> My account </a>';
}
?>
```

> logout.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location:loginform.php');
exit();
?>
```

Comment: "your loginform.php same as default" wat?

Comment: previous as it is.what he display on top of the question.

Comment: thankyou i tried this but when i went on the homepage it didnt show the homepage it just showed the loginform.php